# Riesz-Fischer Theorem applications in language?

Tags: formal-languages

This is a follow-up of the question I posed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084883/chomsky-feynman-thom

I was reading the following comment on Von Neumann (see below) and it occurred to me that what I am asking about Chomsky and Feynman might be, from a methodological standpoint, an instantiation of the same logic of generalization mentioned there:

> [...] This urged Von Neumann to limit the scope of acceptable
>   sequences or functions in both theories to what we know today as
>   spaces ℓ2 and L2 (Von Neumann named them FZ and FΩ, respectively). The
>   Riesz-Fischer theorem, well known to mathematicians since 1907, proved
>   that both spaces were isomorphic and isometric. Given that Von Neumann
>   reasoned that FZ and FΩ (and not Z and Ω!) form the "real analytic
>   substrate" of the matrix and wave mechanics, respectively, and both
>   spaces are isomorphic, the isomorphism means that both theories should
>   yield the same results.

Do you think that Riesz-Fischer theorem (I do not know the specific details of it) might have important consequences for the study of languages and / or for the translation of its results from one kind of formulation to another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case I were on a right track here, I would be extremely interested in knowing the, say, competitive advantage of the Gelfand-Naimark duality over the Riesz-Fischer theorem (since the latter was formulated more than 30 years earlier) for the kind of generalizations at stake here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question positively would require that there is a theory of linguistics which uses functional analysis to model that theory. Otherwise one can not apply that theorem.

Comment: Well, my point is here is such a theory. It is just that linguist are not aware of it while using it in everyday practice. In which way could it be applied? Any cue?